# fbAsyncInit not firing Ionic AngularJS

Tags: android, angularjs, facebook, facebook-graph-api, ionic-framework

I'm trying to set up a **Facebook Login** button in my **Ionic** app, but `window.fbAsyncInit` is not firing at all, and I've tried to fix it through several ways found here in SO (also, I have tried **ngCordova**, but due to local issues, it won't be a possible solution). *Running AngularJS (1.x)*.

Here's my **LoginController.js**:

```
    $scope.$on("$ionicView.beforeEnter", function () {
        window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
            FB.init({
                appId: 'MY_APP_ID_HERE',
                status: true,
                xfbml: true,
                version: 'v2.9'
            });
            FB
                .AppEvents
                .logPageView();
            console.log("INIT.")
        };
    })

    $scope.myFacebookLogin = function () {
        FB
            .login(function (response) {
                if (response.authResponse) {
                    console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
                    FB.api('/me', function (response) {
                        console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
                    });
                } else {
                    console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
                }
            }, {scope: 'email,user_likes'});
    }
```

Here's my **Login Button** (the rest of `Login.html` functions properly):

```
    <button ng-click="myFacebookLogin()" class="button button-balanced" style="background-color: #3b5998">Facebook Login</button>
```

A reference to the facebook script @ my `index.html` (switching to `en_us/all.js` doesn't make a difference):

```
 <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/pt_br/all.js"></script>
```

As of now, anything I've put to run inside the `fbAsyncInit` function doesn't fire, a current example is the `console.log("INIT")` above.
Tests on Chrome do not redirect in any way, and return **`FB.login() called before FB.init()`**. Tests on Android devices just stay still, like you haven't clicked any button.

Just so you guys know, I have followed [Facebook docs' guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/quickstart) thoroughly, and was previously loading the Facebook script through the `function(d, s, id)` found there into my Controller, but then I found it redundant to do so since I put the src in `index.html`.

Comment: where is your`$broadcast` or `$emit`..?

Comment: Does it work when you embedded the SDK the way Facebook recommends? (That is not “redundant”, btw., but done this way to make the script load in an asynchronous, non-blocking way.) The documentation also has tips on how to use it with Angular, did you check out those?

Comment: @Edison as I'm new to Ionic/Angular and haven't found any usage of those in my case, I didn't insert any. If you want to, you could elaborate how and where to use those in my app.
@CBroe I put the function back, and it didn't make a difference (not working). I checked them out and am following them; it did help me a little (thank you), but in the end I had to use a workaround I'm not proud of: putting `FB.init` inside `myFacebookLogin` function, without `fbAsyncInit`.